# List gensym symbol not evaluating inside macro

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to write a macro that takes a list of variables and a body of code and makes sure variables revert to their original values after body of code is executed (exercise 10.6 in Paul Graham's *ANSI Common Lisp*).

However, I'm unclear on why my `gensym` evaluates as I expect it to in one place, but not another similar one (**note**: I know there's a better solution to the exercise. I just want to figure out why the difference in evaluation).

Here's the first definition where the `lst` gensym evaluates to a list inside of the `lambda` passed to the `mapcar`:

```
(defmacro exec-reset-vars-1 (vars body)
  (let ((lst (gensym)))
    `(let ((,lst ,(reduce #'(lambda (acc var) `(cons ,(symbol-value var) ,acc))
                          vars
                          :initial-value nil)))
         ,@body
         ,@(mapcar #'(lambda (var) `(setf ,var (car ,lst)))
                   vars))))
```

But while it works exactly as I expect it to, it's not a correct solution to the exercise because I'm always grabbing the first element of `lst` when trying to reset values. I really want to map over 2 lists. So now I write:

```
(defmacro exec-reset-vars-2 (vars body)
  (let ((lst (gensym)))
    `(let ((,lst ,(reduce #'(lambda (acc var) `(cons ,(symbol-value var) ,acc))
                          vars
                          :initial-value nil)))
         ,@body
         ,@(mapcar #'(lambda (var val) `(setf ,var ,val))
                   vars
                   lst))))
```

But now I get an error that says `#:G3984` is not a list. If I replace it with `(symbol-value lst)` I get an error saying variable has no value. But why not? Why does it have a value inside of the `setf` in `lambda`, but not as an argument passed to `mapcar`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At macroexpansion time you try to map over the value of `lst`, which is a symbol at that time. So that makes no sense.

Trying to get symbol value also makes no sense, since `lst`'s bindings are lexical and `symbol-value` is not a way to access that. Other bindings are not available at that time.

Clearly `lst` has a value at macroexpansion time: a symbol. This is what you see inside the lambda.

You need to make clear what values are computed at macroexpansion time and which at runtime.

An advice about naming:

- `lst` is a poor name in Lisp, use `list`
- the name `lst` makes no sense, since its value is not a list, but a symbol. I'd call it `list-variable-symbol`. Looks long, doesn't it? But it is much clearer. You would now that it is a symbol, used as the name for a variable holding lists.

Comment: Thank you for response. To make sure I understand correctly, in both cases `lst` has the same value during macroexpansion - a symbol. The difference is that in the first case, the `(car ,lst)` is expanded and then its expanded form is evaluated during runtime at which point `lst` is a list; whereas in the second, as the argument to `mapcar`, it's being evaluated during macroexpansion. Is this correct?

Comment: @UnixOne: No. At runtime there is no `lst`, but the variable with a name that was the value of `lst` at macroexpansion time.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you are overthinking it. Imagine this:

```
(defparameter *global* 5)
(let ((local 10))
  (with-reset-vars (local *global*)
    (setf *global* 20)
    (setf local 30)
    ...))
```

I imagine the expansion is as easy as:

```
(defparameter *global* 5)
(let ((local 10))
  (let ((*global* *global*) (local local))
    (setf *global* 20)
    (setf local 30)
    ...)
  (print local)) ; prints 10
(print *global*)  ; prints 5
```

`let` does the reset on it's own so you see that the macro should be very simple just making shadow bindings with `let`, unless I have misunderstood the assignment.

Your overly complicated macros does pretty bad things. Like getting values of global symbols compile time, which would reset them to the time the function that used this instead of before the body.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You are absolutely right. As I noted, I'm aware it's not a good solution to the exercise, I was just wondering why the gensym evaluated it one place but not the other.

Comment: @UnixOne Thats easy. In the first you do `(car lst-gensym-symbol)` which gives you the first part of the `let`-binding that is bound in runtime while in the second you try to map over the same in macroexpansion time but in thet phase it isn't a list but a symbol value. Macros are essentially code transformation and you should not rely on variable bindings.